# parseInt(null) == parseInt(null) is false?

Tags: javascript

```
parseInt(null) == parseInt(null)
```

returns false.

Why? Shouldn't NaN be equal to NaN?

How exactly is NaN implemented in the javascript engine for this to be possible?

Comment: it seems it is like "Does infinity equal to infinity"

Comment: isNaN() is best to test because typeof(NaN)==typeof(42)==true

Comment: We can't use the comparison `=== NaN`, because the value `NaN` is unique in that it does not equal anything. Please see [this](https://javascript.info/number#tests-isfinite-and-isnan).